# My button won't work in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

When I press the button on my emulator it crashes the program and I get an error that says

> Unfortunately 'Name of Project' has stopped.

This is my java code which does not have any red errors in it. It does have a yellow error which says that

> Casting 'findVeiwbyld(R.id.button2) to 'Button' is redundant

which I don't think has anything to do with the fact that the emulator crashes every time I press the button to go to the next page.

```
 Button button1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main3Activity.class));
```

This is my XML code which has no known errors in it.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/homePageButton2"
    android:text="@string/homePageButton2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.14"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.814" />
```

I have tried everything from Invalidating Catches/Restarting to trying a different emulator. I can not think of any other solutions to this problem and I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!!

UPDATE:
This is the message in the log tab after I click the button.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{com.example.millenat19.myapplication/com.example.millenat19.myapplication.Main3Activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
at com.example.millenat19.myapplication.Main3Activity.onCreate(Main3Activity.java:15)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I did not mean to set the constraint to the button and I don't know how to fix this. This is the full Java code that is in the activity which I believe includes the onCreate method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Main3Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text, in the question itself. That said, you've got an image that's too big in `Main3Activity`'s layout, which is causing an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Sorry about the image I am new to stack overflow. Thanks for the help. I deleted the image and that didn't work. I got this message from the logcat output which I posted above.

Comment: Somewhere in `Main3Activity`'s `onCreate()` method, you're trying to cast a `ConstraintLayout` to a `Button`. It's most likely in a `findViewById()` line, where you're using the `R.id` for a `ConstraintLayout`, but trying to assign it to a `Button`.

Comment: Do you mind posting your ```onCreate``` code as well so we can have a look at line 15 where the crash is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying you are trying to cast a `ConstraintLayout` to `Button`. Meaning you might be assigning a ConstraintLayout’s ID from your xml to a Button in your code.

Check for any `ConstraintLayout` you have in xml, get it’s `ID` & search in your code. You might get some clue. Or post the rest of your java code & xml here.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Run your app again and when the emulator crashes check on the Logcat tab what caused the error. It will probably help you find out what is the problem.
Also, there are some stuff that cannot be applied on the emulator, check if your app works on your personal device instead.

[image: This is where the Logcat tac placed]

Comment: Thanks. I ran the program on my personal device and I got the same error. I looked in the log tab like you suggested but I can't figure out what the problem is.